# How to detect in PJSUA2 that a call was unsuccessfull?

Tags: c#-4.0, sip, pjsua2

If i start a call in SIP / PJSUA2 using the CALL function, the OnIncomingCall event in the SIPAccount fires. However, a call CAN fail (non existing target account, or the callee does not answer). Where in SIP or PJSUA2 can i detect, this? Preferably with an event?

Answer (score 1):

You might have got the solution, but answering late so that someone can get help from this post.

If the user didn't answer or not reachable, the state goes to CONNECTED state, you should detect the voice mail activity by writing a separate function. It will go to CONNECTED state in order to enable you to hear the voice message by the provider or by the user.

Comment: Yes, thanks. An example would be really nice. If anyone can provide one, it would be appreciated